# Data Grid View Filtering, Vb.net 2010 and Ms access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a problem on filtering my data on Data Grid View, whenever I search a the same data on my search box the, it continuously add the same data on my datagridview. How can I fix it?

I have two related table.

Here's my code:

```
    Dim sqlqr As String
    Dim sqlqry As String
    Dim src As New BindingSource()
    Dim tbl As DataTableCollection = ndst.Tables
    sqlqry = "SELECT * FROM  tblEmployeeInfo WHERE EmpIdNo='" & txtEmpid.Text & "'"
    sqlqr = "SELECT * FROM tblAttendance WHERE EmpIdNo='" & txtEmpid.Text & "'"
    If sqlqr <> sqlqry Then
        cnn = New OleDbConnection(cs)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlqr, cnn)
        cnn.Open()
        da.Fill(ndst, "tblAttendance")
        Dim vw As New DataView(tbl(0))
        cnn.Close()
        src.DataSource = vw
        dgridDtr.DataSource = src
        ' dgridDtr.DataMember = "tblAttendance"
        src.Filter = String.Format("[EmpIdNo] LIKE '%" & txtEmpid.Text & "%'")
        dgridDtr.Refresh()
    End If
```

here's the screenshot:
 [Heres The image Data Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHMgJ.png)

Comment: could you provide screenshot?

Comment: Hi! I provided the screenshot, can you help me?

Comment: Use an inner join to bring those two tables into a single table. Then set up a parameter to take in the txtEmpid.Text value. fill the dataset and set the datagridview's datasource to the table created in the dataset. There's no need for a view or filter in this case as you are only querying a single id so that filter is not really doing anything for you.

Comment: You do not need to requery if the table has all the attendance info in it.  Just change the DataView row filter

Comment: @Plutonix I think that is his question how to change the DataView row filter correctly

Comment: @codeMonger123 Yah! youre right, I dont know how to change my dataview filter correctly, while filtering it on joined tables, which is tblEmployeeInfo (MainTable) and tblAttendance, EmpId is joined field. Can you help me please. my problem is provided on the image.

Comment: It filters my search field but then everytime I click my Search btn it just add the same value on my filter list at the grid view.